# How to match anything except two or more consecutive spaces in a regex?

Tags: python, regex

How to match anything except two or more consecutive spaces in a regex?

I have a test string like

```
string = ' a      title of foo        b '
```

I would like to capture `title of foo` from string. Basically, this means that we start with any number of spaces, followed by a combination of letters and spaces, but never more than one consecutive space, and then again by any number of spaces.

Attempt (in python).

```
string = '      title of foo        '
match = re.match('\s*([^\s{2,}])*\s*', string)
```

This doesn't work because the square brackets need a list, I think.

Comment: Instead of matching, you could try splitting by 2 or more spaces

Comment: @tobias_k Doesn't the split function take single characters as delimiters? How would this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
>>> string = ' a      title of foo        b '

>>> print re.search(r'\S+(?:(?!\s{2}).)+', string).group()
title of foo
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kR5rK4/1)

Answer (score 3):

It would be easier to just use:

```
stripped_string = string.strip()
```

The function `strip()` removes the whitespace from the start and end of a string.

Comment: You're right this would work, but there are examples that are harder so I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to *match* everything *except* X, it's often simpler to *split* by X instead. In other words: Instead of inverting the regex, invert the operation.

In your case, just [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) by two or more spaces, i.e.`\s{2,}`, and keep what remains.

```
>>> text = '      title of foo       more text   and some more     '
>>> re.split(r'\s{2,}', text)
['', 'title of foo', 'more text', 'and some more', '']
```

This will yield two additional empty matches at the very beginning and the end of the string, but you can easily get rid of them, e.g. using `filter`, or a list comprehension:

```
>>> filter(None, re.split(r'\s{2,}', text))
['title of foo', 'more text', 'and some more']
```

In my opinion, this is much simpler and more concise than a complex regex using lots of lookaheads and stuff to actually match the part that's *not* two or more spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with

```
/(\b\w+(?: \w+\b)+)/
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xC3bZ4/1)

You can use `code generator` on the left side of that page to give you this generated version:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(\b\w+(?: \w+\b)+)')
test_str = u"string = ' a      title of foo        b '"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Your match would then contain only `title of foo` without any of the other strings containing more than a single space between the words.

If you don't know whether your characters will always be `\w` word characters, but can contain anything other than whitespace, you can change `\w` to `\S` so it will match things like

```
rabbit :gold: !whisker?
```

as those contain only a single space between them.

Answer (score 0):

I think this looks fairly clean but it does rely on double spaces existing either side of the text. I prefer anubhava's solution.

```
string = ' a      title of foo        b '
regex=r'(?<=  )(\S.*?\S?)(?=  )'
output=re.findall(regex, string)[0]
```